# How to use Robolectric to test Activity consist of MapFragment?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have a class consist of MapFragment. I am be able to test if the MapFragment is null with

```
startFragment(mapFragment);
assertThat(mapFragment.getView()).isNotNull();
assertThat(mapFragment.getActivity()).isNotNull();  
assertThat(mapFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.mapFragment)).isNotNull();
```

When I use:

> startVisibleFragment(mapFragment);

There is an error occurs:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized

Here is the full code:

**The goal is that if user click on the current location button, then I test if the default location and zoom is correct.**

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = ConsumerBuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class MainActivityUnitTesting {

    private MainActivity mMainActivity;
    private ImageButton currentLocBtn;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mMainActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
        currentLocBtn = (ImageButton) mMainActivity.findViewById(R.id.currentLocBtn);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_MainActivityTestDefaultLocation(){
        startFragment(mMainActivity.mMapFragment);

        currentLocBtn.performClick();

        assertEquals(mMainActivity.mMapFragment.getDefaultLocation(), new LatLng(39.833333, -98.583333));

        assertEquals(mMainActivity.mMapFragment.getmDefaultZoom(), 16);
    }
}
```

1. Did I miss something?
2. Is there any resources that well describe Robolectric testing MapFragment?

Comment: Why do you need to start fragment? Is it not part of activity?

Comment: @EugenMartynov the fragment will be initialized in the activity. I keep getting the CamaraUpdateFactory is not initialized and when i debugged it the object of the GoogleMap is null. That is why I think the fragment is not initialized properly.

Comment: I'm talking about `startFragment(mMainActivity.mMapFragment);`. Is fragment already attached in `onCreate()`?

Comment: @EugenMartynov yep as mentioned above comment

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize the `CameraUpdateFactory` with the class `MapsInitializer`. Put this code in the `setUp()` method:

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer#public-method-summary

**Edit**

Check this guide the section *Other Shadow packages*. You can use the shadow package `org.robolectric:shadows-maps`. This is the link to the library javadoc

http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/maps/package-frame.html

Comment: adding MapsInitializer.initialize(context); in setUp() method is not working. Could you elaborate how to use shadow map class in Robolectric?